# Что быстрее, switch или if else?

Tags: c++, c++17

Я пишу функцию для перемещения угла прямоугольника. Будет ли разница между этими двумя вариациями по скорости?

```
template<rect_corner Corner>
void move_corner(const coords2<value_type>& coords) noexcept {
    if constexpr (Corner == rect_corner::left_top) {
        left = coords.x;
        top = coords.y;
        return;
    }
    if constexpr (Corner == rect_corner::left_bottom) {
        left = coords.x;
        bottom = coords.y;
        return;
    }
    if constexpr (Corner == rect_corner::right_top) {
        right = coords.x;
        top = coords.y;
        return;
    }
    if constexpr (Corner == rect_corner::right_bottom) {
        right = coords.x;
        bottom = coords.y;
        return;
    }
}

void move_corner(const rect_corner corner, const coords2<value_type>& coords) noexcept {
    switch (corner) {
    case rect_corner::left_top:
        left = coords.x;
        top = coords.y;
        break;
    case rect_corner::left_bottom:
        left = coords.x;
        bottom = coords.y;
        break;
    case rect_corner::right_top:
        right = coords.x;
        top = coords.y;
        break;
    default: // corner == right_bottom.
        right = coords.x;
        bottom = coords.y;
        break;
    }
}
```

По идее, первый вариант выберет нужный кусок кода на этапе компиляции, а второй будет выполнять последовательное сравнение, что должно быть дольше. Я замерил скорость выполнения этих функций в цикле и не заметил разницы, но, мне кажется, что первая должна быть быстрее.

Comment: Ну, допустим, *не* последовательное сравнение, но... Неужели у вас все остальное работает настолько быстро, что данная функция стала узким местом программы?...

Comment: Показывайте свой тест целиком. Если значение `corner` известно на этапе компиляции, то компилятор мог просто выкинуть весь `switch`, произведя все необходимые сравнения на этапе компиляции.

Comment: @Harry , я, просто, случайно задумался об этом.

Comment: Если компилятору доступен исходный код функций в местах их вызова (читай, обе объявлены в заголовке), то рассуждения о скорости теряют смысл: оптимизирующий компилятор не транслирует код в исполнимые инструкции буквально. Он строит некоторую модель происходящего, которую затем упрощает (оптимизирует) в зависимости от аргументов конкретного вызова. В вопросе мало данных, но, скорее всего, любой вызов превратится в пару ассемблерных инструкций копирующих числа из одного места в другое. Сделайте исполнимую программу, скомпилируйте её чем-то вроде `gcc -S` и изучите ассемблер.

Comment: Раз не заметили разницы при измерениях, значит ее и нет. Второй вариант гибче, потому что енум можно выбрать в рантайме.

Comment: Почитайте, чем плоха преждевременная оптимизация

Answer (score 1):

Поток управления в инструкциях if-elseif-else является линейным: вычисля­ется условие if и, если оно истинно, выполняется первый блок. В противном случае
продолжается вычисление условий каждого else if и выполнение первого же блока,
условие которого имеет значение t rue. Проверка переменной на равенство для каж­дого из п значений приводит к последовательности if-then-elseifс п блоками. Если все возможные значения равновероятны, такая последовательность if-then-e lseif выполняет О(n) сравнений. При очень частом выполнении (например, при диспетче­ризации событий) стоимость такого кода возрастает многократно.

Инструкция switch также сравнивает переменную с каждым из n значений, но
оператор switch, сравнивающий значение с рядом констант, позволяет компилятору
выполнять ряд полезных оптимизаций.

В часто встречающемся случае, когда требуется проверка на равенство константам, взятым из множества последовательных или почти последовательных значений, инструкция switch компилируется в таблицу переходов, индексируемую тестиру­емым значением или выражением, производным от него. И инструкция switch вы­полняет одну операцию индексации и переходит по указанному в таблице адресу.
Стоимость сравнения равна 0(1), независимо от количества констант для проверки. Такие переходы в таблице не обязаны находиться в последовательном порядке; ком­пилятор может по-своему сортировать таблицу переходов.
Когда константы образуют последовательность с большими разрывами, таблица
переходов становится слишком большой. Компилятор по-прежнему может отсортировать тестируемые константы и сгенерировать код, который выполняет бинарный поиск. Для инструкции switch, выполняющей сравнение с n значениями, наихудшая стоимость поиска составляет O(log2n). В любом случае компилятор никогда не сге­нерирует для инструкции switch код, более медленный, чем для эквивалентной кон­струкции if-else.

Иногда вероятность одной ветви if-elseif-else оказывается гораздо выше про­чих. В этом случае амортизированная производительность инструкции if может
приближаться к константе, если первым проверяется самый вероятный случай.

Отрывок из книги "Оптимизация программ на C++. Проверенные методы повышения производительности | Курт Гантерот"

Comment: Это выглядит как копипаста откуда-то, только пока не понимаю, откуда. :/ Если так, то вам нужно указать источник.

Comment: Команда `if constexpr` появилась только в **c++17** и сравнивать её со `switch` бессмысленно. Она даже быстрее. Работает примерно так : `# ifdef .. # else #  ifdef ..` *Вы рассуждали про обычный **if***